# How can I access the button that was clicked?

Tags: c#, button

I have code in jQuery:

```
// Group of buttons
$(".buttons").click(function() {

    // Do something with one button
    $(this). ...

});
```

I have an another program in C# Window Forms:

```
private void someButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    // How to know which button was clicked?
    // How to get an instance of that button?

}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: cast the sender to a Button type. It's the instance that called the handler.

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like

```
private void someButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var button = (Button)sender;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   private void someButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // How to get an instance of that button?
        Button myButton = ((Button)sender);

        // How to know which button was clicked?
        string buttonId = myButton.ID;
    }
```